# Magento event after filling checkout shipping address

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, event-observer, onepage-checkout, shipping-address

Which magento event gets triggered after filling shipping address on checkout one page as I need to pass some information to a third party api just after shipping address.

Answer (score 0):

It looks there is no event for that. But there is after choosing the shipping method instead `checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method`.

[Check list of events within Magento](https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-9/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think it is checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping rather than checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method because it gets call after checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping.                                                  Because after filling shiping address we get move on to next step i.e. shipping method.

Comment: Check function `saveShippingMethodAction()` in `class Mage_Checkout_OnepageController`

Comment: saveShippingAction() in class Mage_Checkout_OnepageController worked for me.

Comment: You anted to fire an event rather.

Comment: yes, i was looking for an event and I could not find that particular event and even you also told ,there is no as such event for it...so i have called an observer on this.